# php find xml node thanks to isset variable form url

Tags: xpath, simplexml, php, isset

I have a single.php page where I want to load individual post.

To do this I have some links in my index.php that allows to load single.php page :

```
<a href="single.php?blog_no=12">Post 12</a> 
<a href="single.php?blog_no=11">Post 11</a>   
<a href="single.php?blog_no=10">Post 10</a>
```

I get the variable in the url in my single.php page and I want to find (and display), in a xml file, the element that correspond to this variable:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["blog_no"])) {

$i = $_GET["blog_no"];

$elements = new SimpleXMLElement('data.xml', null, true);

$query = $elements->xpath(" /elements/element[@id='$i'] ");

foreach($query as $element) {

    echo $elements->element['size'];
    echo $elements->element['category'];
    echo $elements->element->title;

}
?>
```

Here an example of my xml file:

```
<elements>

<element id="12" size="square" category="portfolio">
    <tag tag="printer printing 3d apple iphone 5 bumper case"></tag>
    <icon class="icon-picture"></icon>
    <urlpage url="/contact/contact.html"></urlpage>
    <urlimage src='./Post thumbnail images/01.png'></urlimage>
    <date date="8 Apr"></date>
    <title>Minimal Bumper for iPhone 5 : Protect your iphone with a lightwheight and protect full case </title>
</element>

<element id="11" size="normal" category="portfolio">
    <tag tag="printer printing 3d apple iphone 5 case slim"></tag>
    <icon class="icon-picture"></icon>
    <urlpage url="/portfolio/11.html"></urlpage>
    <urlimage src='./Post thumbnail images/tape-dribbble.jpg'></urlimage>
    <date date="21 Jan"></date>
    <title>UltraSlim case</title>
</element>

</elements>
```

But nothing works.

Comment: *"But nothing works."* is not a valid problem description. Before you ask a question here, ensure you've got error logging and reporting enabled and set to the highest level, then track all notices, warnings and errors and fix them first. This will spare you so many questionmarks because PHP will tell where problems are - like in your example code here not doing the proper xpath.

Comment: After your last edit(s) your code even runs out of the box (http://eval.in/30703). So what is your question here?

Comment: This code don't have any error of course but it don't work correctly. It always get the first xml node...

Comment: That's because of the way the original code is accessing the original doc in the `foreach` loop, rather than the results of the xpath query. There were more problems in the original code than just the variable substitution.

Comment: No, it get's the node you ask for. The `foreach` also puts it into `$element`, but *you need to use that variable for output then*. If you don't, then you don't. See http://eval.in/private/ed061ca92bcd48

Comment: It's not working like that on my webserver... For sure! It seems it comes for the variable `$i = $_GET["blog_no"];`

Comment: @Freaky: Might be, however then your question asks for the wrong. Please troubleshoot your script on your webserver first. E.g. `var_dump($_GET);` and so on. It's really simple and acutally, it's something you need to do anyway, we can not do that for you.

Comment: My question is right! Now of course it's "wrong" because we try to resolve it so the code change in the time. that the main principle on how to resolve something. On my server I get no errors. The php script don't find the xml element even if it exist. So I can't give you an error! Maybe it's just a problem of php version... (but I set it up in my htaccess file...). I will use my answer code. It works but this is not the best way to do it... Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were quite close to it, do it like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['blog_no'])) { 

    $id = $_GET['blog_no'];
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
    $element = $xml->xpath("//element[@id='$id']")[0];
    echo "$element[size] - $element[category]<br />$element->title<br />";

} else {

    echo "No post selected!"
}
```

Explanation:

1. in xpath, `//element` means to select every `<element>` at any position in the XML
2. xpath will always return an array, the `[0]` will select only the 1st match. This syntax will work in PHP >=5.4, if you're below, let me know and I'll post the right code.
3. No need for `foreach`, there can only be one `<element>` selected, because the `id` is unique (I guess).

See it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/LY3itL

Comment: Thank you for the answere. But on my server it don't works.There is an error here : `$element = $xml->xpath("//element[@id='$id']")[0];` call to a member function xpath() on a Non-object. it seems that I have some trouble with the variable... I have set up php 5.4 in my htaccess file

Comment: @freaky did you read the contents of the file into the `$x` variable?

Comment: Yes I load the xml file an put in $x... Maybe I didn't write it correctly : `$x = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');`

Comment: Ah OK, you should just try replacing `$xml = simplexml_load_string($x);` with `$xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');`

Comment: There isn't any error like this but the echo just display for example : `$element[size]`. It seems that it didn't success to find the xml element node...

Comment: By removing double brackets in the echo it works now!!! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Cool, at last! Got there in the end :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['blog_no'])) 
{
    $i = $_GET['blog_no'];

    if (file_exists('data.xml')) 
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');

        $query = '/elements/element[@id="'.$i.'"]';

        $elements = $xml->xpath($query);

        foreach ($elements as $element) 
        {
            echo $element['size'];
            echo $element['category'];
            echo $element->title;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        exit('Failed to open data.xml.');
    }
}
?>
```

See above Xpath working here: [codepad.viper-7.com/QgYeqK](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QgYeqK).

Thanks go to @michi for introducing [codepad.viper-7.com](http://codepad.viper-7.com).

Comment: thank you for the  answere but it's not working. Errors occur here :`$xml = new simplexml_load_file('data.xml'); ` and here `$query = $xml->xpath('/elements/element[@id={$i}]');' and here `foreach($query as $element) `

Comment: Yeh sorry. I've updated my answer above. Can you try again please.

Comment: I tried with your updated code. There are't any errors but nothing is displayed. I think it comes from the foreach. See my answere, it works but it's maybe not the best way to do it...

Comment: @freaky it's annoying the xpath method isn't working for you. I've updated one more time. So you can try that again if you want. Gotta sleep now. But if that still doesn't work, I'll investigate and fix tomorrow.

Comment: your `$xml` already represents the `<elements>` node, so don't put it into your xpath.

Comment: @michi thanks for the reference to codepad-viper7.com. I can now see that my xpath also works. Using `/elements` just means I am using an absolute reference from the root, so only `<element>` that are an immediate child of `<elements>`. Something to bear in mind with `//element` is that it will return any `<element>` that could be at any position in the document.

Comment: @davmos welcome. Given his XML, I see no reason to not use `//element`, but of course, it will select any element. Note that also `xpath("element[@id=...` will get the same result, because `<elements>` is already represented by `$xml`.

Comment: Agreed @michi, no probs as long as we've highlighted the differences of both approaches. Your answer got my +1.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution :

```
if(isset($_GET["blog_no"])) {

    if (file_exists('data.xml')) {

        $elements = new SimpleXMLElement('data.xml', null, true);

        foreach ($elements->element as $element) {  

            if ($element['id'] == $_GET["blog_no"]) {
                echo $element['size'];
                echo $element['category'];
                echo $element->title;

                break;
            }
        }
    }else {
        exit('Failed to open data.xml.');
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's the best way to do it but it works great.

Comment: Seems you got some inspiration from my answer :)

Comment: Yes! thank your for the if file exist!

Comment: Maybe I need to add a return in the if to stop the foreach in order to avoid to execute again and again the foreach? I don't know how it works with php.

Comment: Sure, to do that you can just write `break;` after last `echo`.

Comment: ok. return; do not the same thing in php?

Comment: `break` just exits the `foreach` and code after that will continue to run. `return` ends the whole script.

Comment: this is how to do it without xpath - but there's actually no need to do it without xpath.

Comment: @freaky: If you want to understand which mistake you made, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16635323/367456